# Missing bundle entity, entity type paragraphs_type from field_instance.yml file

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, migration, drupal-8

I'm currently trying to migrate my D7 site to D8 and one of the things migrating is field_collections to paragraphs. I have a field_collection call "field_sidebar_callouts". I want to migrate that to paragraphs.

Everything is migrating correctly until it reaches to field_instance.yml file. It throws an error call this:

> Missing bundle entity, entity type paragraphs_type, entity id r_callouts

Is the instance yml file importing half the id? How come the entity id is only "r_callouts" and not "field_sidebar_callouts".

Did my field_instance.yml get auto-generated incorrectly?

Any help would be amazing!

Here's my instance file:

```
uuid: 295c39a9-1857-4d53-a342-92a16ae71223
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: upgrade_d7_field_instance
class: Drupal\migrate_drupal\Plugin\migrate\FieldMigration
field_plugin_method: alterFieldInstanceMigration
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags:
 - 'Drupal 7'
 - Configuration
 migration_group: migrate_drupal_7
label: 'Field instance configuration'
source:
 plugin: d7_field_instance
 constants:
  status: true
process:
 type:
  -
  plugin: process_field
  source: type
  method: getFieldType
 entity_type:
  -
   plugin: get
   source: entity_type
  -
   plugin: static_map
   map:
    field_collection_item: paragraph
    paragraphs_item: paragraph
  bypass: true
field_name:
  -
   plugin: get
   source: field_name
bundle:
 -
  plugin: static_map
  source: bundle
  bypass: true
  map:
    comment_node_forum: comment_forum
-
  plugin: paragraphs_process_on_value
  source_value: entity_type
  expected_value: field_collection_item
  process:
    plugin: substr
    start: 6
label:
 -
  plugin: get
  source: label
description:
 -
  plugin: get
  source: description
required:
 -
  plugin: get
  source: required
status:
 -
  plugin: get
  source: constants/status
allowed_values:
 - 
  plugin: sub_process
  source: allowed_vid
  process:
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: upgrade_d7_taxonomy_vocabulary
      source: vid
settings:
  0:
   plugin: d7_field_instance_settings
   source:
    - settings
    - widget
    - field_definition
field_collection:
  plugin: field_collection_field_instance_settings
default_value_function:
 -
  plugin: get
  source: ''
default_value:
 -
  plugin: d7_field_instance_defaults
  source:
    - default_value
    - widget
translatable:
 -
  plugin: get
  source: translatable
settings/title:
 -
  plugin: static_map
  source: settings/title
  bypass: true
  map:
    disabled: 0
    optional: 1
    required: 2
destination:
 plugin: 'entity:field_config'
migration_dependencies:
 required:
  - upgrade_d7_field
optional:
  - upgrade_d7_node_type
  - upgrade_d7_comment_type
  - upgrade_d7_taxonomy_vocabulary
  - upgrade_d7_field_collection_type
```